# Overlay between two PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I'm looking for a way to get the result of an overlay between two pdf documents.

We have a document with a single page and only a header and another document with multiple pages and full content (header and body). We're looking for way to generate an overlay pdf between those documents, so that the resulting document with the content gets its header overwritten in each page with the single page document header. Basically like this:

[image]

Is there a opensource c# library, which can handle this and not convert the text to a picture.
I looked at [PdfSharp](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/) and [docnet](https://github.com/GowenGit/docnet), but couldn't figure it out with either of them.

So far we are using [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#overlaypdf), but we'd like to get rid of the java dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with PDFsharp: draw a white rectangle that hides the original header, then draw the new header on top of the rectangle.

Drawback: The old header is still contained in the document.